# Help! Symmetry isn't completely symmetrical on Z angled faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The model origin is in the world centre, as well as the cubes, But for some reason the front angle isn't actually symmetrical. Why?

Comment: hello, hard to understand your image, but maybe you have rotated your object? in that case apply the rotation

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.